# How to change the state of appBar() to show different strings, based on what the user picks?

Tags: flutter, dart, timer

I am making a rather simple app, but I got to perhaps the most complicated part. I am a beginner in flutter, so I need some help here. I have an app that contains a timer functionality. The timer is for practicing some scrambles for Rubik's cubes. The timer is tap activated, meaning, if you tap the screen, the timer starts, and when you click it again, it stops. Here is what I want to achieve with this timer: I want the user to pick an option for what scrambles they want to practice. So, if, say, the user picks '2x2' and then chooses 'CLL', I want the scrambles shown on the timer screen to update, to show only scrambles for 'CLL'. If the user picks 3x3 and then 'OLL', I want the scrambles to update to show only 'OLL' scrambles. I hope that makes sense. (For reference, I am trying to accomplish the same functionality that this website accomplishes: [Notice how when you start and then stop the timer, the scramble above chances. Also notice how when you switch the option from '3x3' to '2x2', the scrambles change to suit the different cube. This is exactly what I want to accomplish](https://cstimer.net)

Here is the code that I need help with. I have multiple screens, so I will link them all below:

This is the screen I have for my 'timer screen'. This is where the timer interface is.

```
import 'dart:async';
import '2x2TimerAlgstes.dart';

 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class StopWatchWidget extends StatefulWidget {
 const StopWatchWidget({super.key});

 @override
  State<StopWatchWidget> createState() => _StopWatchWidgetState();
   }

  class _StopWatchWidgetState extends State<StopWatchWidget> {
   final Stopwatch _stopwatch = Stopwatch();
    String stopWatchText = '00:00';
  void startStopWatch() {
     if (_stopwatch.isRunning) {
     _stopwatch.stop();
   } else {
     stopWatchText = '00:00';
      _stopwatch
       ..reset()
         ..start();
     }  

Timer.periodic(const Duration(milliseconds: 1), (timer) {
  setState(() {
    if (!_stopwatch.isRunning) {
      timer.cancel();
    }
    stopWatchText =
        '${(_stopwatch.elapsed.inMinutes % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${(_stopwatch.elapsed.inSeconds % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';
  });
});
   }

   @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text(
      'Trainer',
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent),
    ),
    actions: [
      IconButton(
        onPressed: () {
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
              actions: [
                Center(
                  child: TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => const TwoTimerAlgsets(),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    child: const Text(
                      '2x2',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent, fontSize: 25),
                    ),
                  )
              ],
              title: const Text('Choose Algset:'),
            ),
          );
        },
        icon: const Icon(
          Icons.add_circle_outline,
          color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
        ),
        splashColor: Colors.transparent,
        highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
    ],
  ),
  body: Column(
    // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Container(
        height: 60,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: const Center(
          child: Text(
            "F U R U' R' F'", // **I need this scramble to update based on what the user picks**
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      const SizedBox(height: 10),
      Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 665,
          child: TextButton(
            style: ButtonStyle(
              overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent),
            ),
            onPressed: startStopWatch,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 145.0),
              child: Text(
                stopWatchText,
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 50, color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
  }
 }
```

You will notice a TextButton wrapped in an AlertDialog() and this is the code I have the TextButton() linked to. This is where the user will pick what scrambles they want to practice:

```
import 'package:testing_stuff_ignore/2x2Stuff/Ortega_Screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:testing_stuff_ignore/ContainerShowingDifferentAlgsets.dart';

class TwoTimerAlgsets extends StatelessWidget {
 const TwoTimerAlgsets({super.key});

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool isPressed = true;
    void displayCLLScrambles() {
      Text('555555');
    }

void buttonPressed() {
  if (buttonPressed == true) {
    displayCLLScrambles;
  }
}

return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text('2x2 Algsets'),
  ),
  body: InkWell(
    onTap: () {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => const OrtegaScreen(),
        ),
      );
    },
    child: Center(
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          InkWell(
            child: ContainerShowingDifferentAlgsets(name: 'Ortega'),
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            child: ContainerShowingDifferentAlgsets(name: 'CLL'),
          ),
          ContainerShowingDifferentAlgsets(name: 'EG-1'),
          ContainerShowingDifferentAlgsets(name: 'EG-2'),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
   }
 }
```

I realize it may be a bit confusing, although I hope it is not too confusing. Here are some pictures of my screens, if it helps at all:

This is what happens when you click on the IconButton(), which is located in the first screen: [image: Here is where the user will pick what scrambles they want to practice]

This is what happens when the user clicks on an option, in this example, when the user clicks '2x2'

[image: Once the user clicks an option, a new screen shows different 'sets' the user can practice]

So again, if the user now picks 'CLL', I want the scrambles in my timer appBar to update, showing only CLL scrambles. [image: The picture below will contain a very basic summary if what I want to accomplish]

I've tried making some functions showing scrambles for different options, but I don't know how to update the state of the app to show these scrambles. I hope this all makes sense, and any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I think you need one of the [state management approaches](https://docs.flutter.dev/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options), I recommend [Riverpod](https://riverpod.dev/)

Comment: How would I use Riverbed once installed?